# Component not updating page style with prop value

Tags: reactjs

I am unsure about the reason this is happening but the below code is not actually visually showing the image I am passing through, if I have a look into dev tools on chrome I can see the correct image written there however it's not loading through.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function Banner(props) {
  const pngname = props.categoryName.replace(" ","").toLowerCase() + "tag"
  return (
    <div className={`bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('/image/${pngname}.png')]`}>
      <div style={{background: props.categoryColour+"59"}} className={`h-[300px] mb-6 flex items-center text-white dark:text-black `}>
        <div className='container mx-auto flex justify-center h-100'>
          <div>
            <span style={{opacity: 1}} className='text-5xl'>{props.categoryName}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  )
}
```

One thing I did notice is if I change the props.categoryName to a color such as #E8EAEF

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react"
export default function Banner(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{backgroundImage: props.categoryColour}} className={`h-[300px] mb-6 flex items-center text-white dark:text-black`}>
        <div className='container mx-auto flex justify-center h-100'>
          <div>
            <span className='text-5xl'>{props.categoryName}</span>
            <p className='text-5xl'>{props.categoryColour}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
  )
}
```

the above works, however the below doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Banner(props) { 
  return (
    <div style={{backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to right, ${props.categoryColour}, rgba(255,0,0,0));`}} className={`h-[300px] mb-6 flex items-center text-white dark:text-black`}>
        <div className='container mx-auto flex justify-center h-100'>
          <div>
            <span className='text-5xl'>{props.categoryName}</span>
            <p className='text-5xl'>{props.categoryColour}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
  )
}
```

Comment: In the third codeblock, it could be an issue with the value of `props.categoryColour` it may need to be: `linear-gradient(to right, #${props.categoryColour}, rgba(255,0,0,0));` (depending on the value you expect to get in that. For the first codeblock, it is likely the same issue. You are passing the `pngname` as a class, not as a style property

Comment: @Harrison I should have mentioned, but the variable does include the #. In regards to passing the pngname as a class and not as a style property. What do you mean by this?

Comment: your code read: `<div className={`bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('/image/${pngname}.png')]`}>` which means that in the HTML you get `class="bg-cover bg-center bg-[url('/image/path-to-png.png')]"` I imagine what you want is to put `url('/image/path-to-png.png')` into style like this: `style={{ backgroundImage: "url('/image/path-to-png.png')" }}`

Comment: @Harrison, this actually helpped me fix the issue I was having. Thanks a lot!